# Get an error "enum switch case label must be the unqualified name" even thought using correct switch case

Tags: java, gradle, enums, switch-statement, build.gradle

I have enum from third party library like this

```
public enum ErrorCode {
   TIMEOUT,
   UNKNOWN,
   CANCELLED
}
```

I am using swith case in my code like this

```
ErrorCode errorCode = result.errorCode; -> from API

switch(errorCode) {
 case TIMEOUT:
   return ...
 case UNKNOWN:
   return ...
 case CANCELLED:
   return ...
}
```

but when build i got an error like this

```
error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
case CANCELLED:
     ^
```

Background : `CANCELLED` is newly added enum from third party on same version of library that i use

illustarion:
I used version 1.5.0
enum before is like this

```
public enum ErrorCode {
   TIMEOUT,
   UNKNOWN
}
```

then third party update enum in version 1.5.0 become like this

```
public enum ErrorCode {
   TIMEOUT,
   UNKNOWN,
   CANCELLED
}
```

I don't know why this happen only in one enum. Can you help me to explain why this issue is happen and how to fix this problem ?

Comment: You are compiling with an old version of the library? How are you managing the dependency?

Comment: I am compiling with latest library from third party. I managed this dependency using build.gradle. third party updating enum on same version of library that i use

Comment: Your question reads as though different versions of version 1.5.0 exist with each version of the enum. If so, the third party has done the wrong thing.

Comment: Since the error message is about the newly added value, I suspect that you're actually compiling against the old version, even though you're certain that you're compiling against the new version. I'd investigate further...